# Sql Server 2005 connection log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, system-administration

I have multiple databases on one SQL Server 2005 server. I would like to know a way using which I can see all the connections made to a particular database today and the activities performed.

Thanks in advance

Joe

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918(SQL.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by MichealGG, SQL Profiler is a pretty good tool for monitoring connections & events 
for an instance of SQL Server. Run SQL profiler and start a new trace. You can even filter    for specific event classes that you are interested in.

Just be carefull not to leave the trace running indefinitely or for a long time as it takes up a lot of server  resources.